# Android - Capture Enter and Delete events from soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyevent

I have an **EditText** and I want to capture when the user click *Enter* or *Delete*. I tried with the **onKeyListener** but it didn't work.

```
    myEdiText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACKSPACE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I long press the Enter button it shows the Toast for the Enter, but I want to show it on a single press. On the other hand the toast for the Delete never has shown.

**EDIT**
the Toast for the Delete is showing up when I press the hardware back button

Comment: Are you using a physical android keyboard?

Comment: No I'm using soft android keyboard.

Comment: OnKeyListener has problems with softkeyboards. Use a textwatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnKeyListener` only works with physical keyboards. You'll have to use a `TextWatcher`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!